# Getting around "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm looking to create a small app, where some elements will be nested in another. While developing the app I'm trying to segment each component into its own file (children), returning a function with 2 components in each `Renderer` and `values`.

The goal of this approach is to

1. Making the code more readable, and easier to develop
2. make the data in the class easily available for exporting purposes.

However, I experienced 2 issues, in the process

1. when the child-object uses `useState`, and renders an increasing amount of objects (say increasing an array size, rendering each element), the effect which increases the child-object size stops functioning (does nothing at all)
2. If the parent (so to speak) contains an array of child objects each with a render function, increasing the size of this array leads to dynamically increasing the number of hooks.

I don't see a good way to get around this, and I'm hoping to get some clarity with this question

The simplest way to illustrate this is with a small example.
In the code below I've created a child component F, which holds a list of rows that it should render. This works all fine when F is the only element of the app. However, if the app contains a list of "F"'s, which may increase in size, this causes an increase in number of hooks.

What would be some possible ways around this, while maintaining the same or similar functionality?

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, Button } from 'react-native';

const F = () => {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([1]);

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    setRows((old) => [...old, old.length + 1]);
  };

  const render = () => {
    return (
      <View>
      {rows.map((row, index) => (
        <Text>"index"</Text>
      ))}
      <Button title="Row button" style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#aff'}}  onPress={() => handleAddRow}/>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return ({values: rows, Renderer : render});  
};

const App = () => {
  const [fs, setFs] = useState([F()]);

  const handleAddFs = () => {
    setFs((old) => [...old, F()]);
  };


  return ( 
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
      <View>
      {fs.map((fi, index) => ( 
        fi.Renderer()
      ))}
      {fs.map((fi, index) => ( 
        <Text>`{fi.values.length}`</Text>
      ))}
      </View>
      <Button
        title="Press me"
        color="#f194ff"
        onPress={() => handleAddFs()}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: As a react dev for the past decade, I can tell that this approach is not making it any clearer for me. It isn't very clear, why you would pass the Renderer and render it in the parent.
Why can't you have the row's state in the Parent App component and pass it as a child to the F component?

Comment: You should stick which the common pattern in react world. I am not have any problems with it. This will make it more difficult to understand for other developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently what's being rendered is the App component. It has 1 state. Upon clicking button that calls `handleAddFs`, you're calling a new function which creates another state `[rows,setRows]`. This isn't something that's allowed in React. What you can do however is have the state be rendered together with the App and pass the state as a prop to your `F()` function like done below here :

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, Button } from 'react-native';

const F = (rows,setRows) => {


  const handleAddRow = () => {
    setRows((old) => [...old, old.length + 1]);
  };

  const render = () => {
    return (
      <View>
      {rows.map((row, index) => (
        <Text>"index"</Text>
      ))}
      <Button title="Row button" style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#aff'}}  onPress={() => handleAddRow}/>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return ({values: rows, Renderer : render});  
};

const App = () => {
  const [fs, setFs] = useState([F()]);
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([1]);

  const handleAddFs = () => {
    setFs((old) => [...old, F(rows,setRows)]);
  };


  return ( 
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
      <View>
      {fs.map((fi, index) => ( 
        fi.Renderer()
      ))}
      {fs.map((fi, index) => ( 
        <Text>`{fi.values.length}`</Text>
      ))}
      </View>
      <Button
        title="Press me"
        color="#f194ff"
        onPress={() => handleAddFs()}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

React hooks [can only be used  at the top level of your component or your Hooks](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#caveats). Also, function components should [return a render element](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_components.asp).

If you want to pass props to children and update parents dynamically, you can follow a pattern similar to the **`UpdateParentState`** example below. However, it's an expensive way of cummunication between a parent and children, as every time any of children changes, the parent and all children state will update (re-render).

If parent props needs to be updated only for next action, A less costly but more complicated solution would be **`UpdateParrentRef`**, below.

You might also consider using: [useReducer](https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer) or [createContext](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context).

**UpdateParrentState**

```js
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, Button } from "react-native";

const FRenderer = ({ onChange, level, rows: initialRows }) => {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(initialRows);

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    const newRow = [...rows, rows.length + 1];
    setRows(newRow);
    onChange({ rows: newRow });
  };

  const renderItem = (row, index) => <Text key={index}>"index": {row}</Text>;
  return (
    <View>
      {rows.map(renderItem)}
      <Text>{`level: ${level} Total rows: ${rows.length}`}</Text>
      <Button title="Add row" onPress={handleAddRow} />
    </View>
  );
};

const BriefRenderer = ({ rows, level }) => (
  <Text>{`level: ${level} Total Rows: ${rows.length}`}</Text>
);

const createF = ({ level = 1 } = {}) => ({
  level,
  Renderer: FRenderer,
  rows: [level % 3 ? 1 : "fizz"],
  BriefRenderer,
});

const UpdateParrentState = () => {
  const [fs, setFs] = useState(() => [createF()]);

  const handleAddFs = () => {
    setFs([...fs, createF({ level: fs.length + 1 })]);
  };

  const onChange = (changes, changeIndex) => {
    setFs((prev) =>
      prev.map((item, index) => (index === changeIndex ? { ...item, ...changes } : item))
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
      <View>
        {fs.map((fi, index) => (
          <fi.Renderer key={index} {...fi} onChange={(changes) => onChange(changes, index)} />
        ))}
        {fs.map((fi, index) => (
          <fi.BriefRenderer key={index} {...fi} />
        ))}
      </View>
      <Button title="Press me" color="#f194ff" onPress={handleAddFs} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default UpdateParrentState;
```

**UpdateParrentRef**

```js
const UpdateParrentRef = ({ initiaFs = [createF()] }) => {
  const [fs, setFs] = useState(initiaFs);
  const fsInfo = useRef(initiaFs);

  const handleAddFs = () => {
    const newItem = createF({ level: fs.length + 1 });
    setFs([...fs, newItem]);
    fsInfo.current = [...fsInfo.current, newItem];
  };

  const onChange = (changes, index) => {
    fsInfo.current[index] = { ...fsInfo.current[index], ...changes };
  };

  const logInfo = () => console.log(fsInfo.current);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
      <View>
        {fs.map((fi, index) => (
          <fi.Renderer key={index} {...fi} onChange={(changes) => onChange(changes, index)} />
        ))}
      </View>
      <Button title="Press me" color="#f194ff" onPress={handleAddFs} />

      <Button title="Log info" onPress={logInfo} />
      <Text>{`Total items: ${fs.length}`}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the problem is that you're trying to invert the natural data flow of React which is that data flows from parent to child.

You've got `F`, which looks like a component because it contains `useState` - but it's called as a function (which means it can't actually have state) and you're **returning the values from the called function to the parent so the parent can render the state of the child**

That's inverting the data flow, just keep the **necessary state in the parent and let it flow down the tree**.

You'll know when you're trying to fight against React's natural data flow, because that's when stuff starts to get complicated and hard (like your original code). React is easy, it's actually trivially simple, if you don't fight it.

Here's the re-written code that accomplishes the same goal:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, Button } from 'react-native';

const F = () => {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([1]);

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    setRows((old) => [...old, old.length + 1]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <View>
      {rows.map((row, index) => (
        <Text>"index"</Text>
      ))}
      <Button title="Row button" style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#aff'}}  onPress={() => handleAddRow}/>
      </View>
      <Text>`{rows.length}`</Text> /* you can include this part in the JSX of the child instead of returning it to the parent */
    </>
  );

};

const App = () => {
  const [fs, setFs] = useState(1); // I'd change this to a number, it's all that matters, but you can keep an array of `undefineds` as well

  const handleAddFs = () => setFs(f => f+1)

  return ( 
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
      <View>
         {Array.from({length:fs}).map(() => <F/>)}
      </View>
      <Button
        title="Press me"
        color="#f194ff"
        onPress={() => handleAddFs()}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

It's important to note that my code above ignores the fact that [rendering JSX inside a map call always needs keys](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key). That can be a topic for another question, or you can just read about why you need to do it in the docs.

Comment: This is missing a major point. In the dummy example it is not that important, but in practice the state in F would hold non-dummy data. And while the depth here is 2 (app/F), it may be much greater in practice. I' would like to avoid each step being massive holding all the data logic. Rather let app be a container which calls functions/objects-methods etc. to achieve rendering and functions like saving of data (currently stored in the dummy variable rows).

Comment: @Oliver this example is only built off of the code that you have shown. It’s all I had to go on. While the code sample might not be applicable because it was trivialized to something that’s not real world for you, the line about “letting the data flow down through the tree” is 100% accurate. Don’t do react upside down, it’ll only lead to a word of pain. Of you want to update your example to be more realistic I’d be happy to take another crack at it. React has a guiding principle of “life state up” - use it, don’t fight the framework.